# Textures are missing (colored magenta) in Material Preview, yet show up in Rendered View

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, image

I have a model that I'm overlaying several images over. Each of these images are texture-painted masks and, through a mix shader, are being assigned different textures - all within a single material.

This has caused an issue. I like to texture-paint in Material Preview mode; however, in that mode, the model turns magenta as if the textures are missing. I've packed the textures, saved them to another location, restarted Blender multiple times, yet they still appear magenta.

The strange thing is, when I switch the viewport over to "Rendered View", it appears with all the textures on it. I can also render the scene and the textures appear fine.

*Material Preview:*
[image: Material Preview]

*Rendered View:*
[image: Rendered View]

TLDR: Model appears magenta in Material Preview, but show correct textures in Rendered View and final render, despite the textures being referenced correctly (I hope).

- Engine: Cycles
- I have 1 UV map on the model.
- I've painted with the "missing" textures working before. The problem arose when I added another blank image for more texture painting. Yes, that one is saved to my computer/packed in the .blend.
- My normals are facing the correct way.

Comment: Hi, try to show your shading node setup also.